# Drawer with toolbar as appbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar, drawer, nestedrecyclerview

I'm trying to create an app which uses a DrawerLayout to show several options which are used to influence the results presented do the user. Here's an emulator capture that shows the current result:

[image: Using a drawer to show the filtering options]

Now, I'm also using a Toolbar with the only purpose of showing the open menu button on the top left of the screen:

[image: Adding the toolbar to the drawerlayout]

In order to achieve this, I've followed the steps described on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer). Here's the XML for my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#FFE7E8ED">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swiper"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/lista"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="true"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_viewer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've added a SwipeRefreshLayout to let the users refresh the data that is shown in the RecyclerView. In this case, I've got nested RecyclerViews because the data I need to show is grouped by category:

```
category A
   news 1
   news 2
category B
   news 3
....
```

Now, my problem is that when the app loads, it will "jump" to the cardview that wraps the list of news. This image shows the problem I'm facing:

[image: By default, the title is not shown]

The red box shows where the beginning of the category item is (just some plain text). Just to make my point clear, here's another screen capture of the layout tool:

[image: The structure of the layout capture by the layout tool of android studio]

As you can see, the title is there, but it gets scrolled up behind the toolbar. It's as if the inner list promotes itself for the top of the screen...

Just to be thorough, I'm also showing the layouts I'm using in the top RecyclerView's item template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.WindowTitle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lista_noticias"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the template I'm using for the inner RecyclerView's item template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:maxHeight="140dp"
    android:minHeight="140dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="2dp">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="top|center_vertical"
            android:lines="3"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publishDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="10/10/2018 13:50"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As I said, it's as if the news lists scrolls the UI so that it shows the first item. I've also noticed that if there aren't enough items for getting a scroll on the first group, then everything works out great. Here's an image that shows that:

[image: First group doesn't require scrolling, then it works well]

However, as soon as I pick one category that has more news than available screen space, then it will simply position the view on the first item of the inner list.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks guys!

Luis

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding `focusableInTouchMode="true"` to my top ConstraintLayout ended up solving this issue...